# Sas entreprise équivalent of x’cp …. …’

Tags: sas

Is there an function which can copy a file from one folder to another one in sas enterprise? I know it’s the command cp in an Unix environment. I’m searching a solution which doesn’t make me change the default settings in sas.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FCOPY()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/n10dz22b5ixohin1vwzilweetek0.htm) function.

Example from documentation:

```
   /* Set MSGLEVEL to I to write messages from FCOPY to the log. */
options msglevel=i;

filename src 'source.txt';
filename dest 'destination.txt';

   /* Create an example file to copy. */
data _null_;
   file src;
   do i=1, 2105, 300312, 400501;
      put i:words256.;
   end;
run;

   /* Copy the records of SRC to DEST. */
data _null_;
   length msg $ 384;
   rc=fcopy('src', 'dest');
   if rc=0 then
      put 'Copied SRC to DEST.';
   else do;
      msg=sysmsg();
      put rc= msg=;
   end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your SAS Session is locked down, you could try to use the [RENAME()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p14axci3mo3egan1okbcydvbt433.htm) function.

> If the SAS session in which you are specifying the FILEEXIST function is in a locked-down state, and the pathname specified in the function has not been added to the lockdown path list, then the function will fail and a file access error related to the locked-down data will not be generated in the SAS log unless you specify the SYSMSG function.

Don't get disturbed by the FILEEXIST, the documentation team forgot to change the function name when copy pasting the description...

```
data _null_;
  rc = rename("\\path\to\file.csv",
              "\\another\path\file.csv",
              "file");
  put rc=;
run;
```

Comment: Nice to learn something new! Thanks Kermit.

Answer (score 0):

If your platform administrator enabled the `x` command, you can just pass the command to your operating system.

```
x 'cp /from/path/data.file /to/path';
```

or with some typical macro variables

```
x "cp &fromPath/&dataFile &toPath";
```

Otherwise, it is impossible.